# R: how to pass in a reference to the variable in glm or lm?

Tags: r, formula, glm, lm

so let's say i have a named vector:

```
sorted = c(1,2,3)
names(sorted) = c("A","B","C")
```

and it'll look like following:

```
> sorted
A    B    C
1    2    3
```

so this is a vector named A,B,C, and has value 1,2,3 respectively.

and i also have a sample data:

```
data.ex = as.data.frame(matrix(rep(c(1,2,3,4),3), nrow = 3, ncol = 3))
colnames(data.ex) = c("A","B","C")
```

so this data frame has 3 columns named A,B,C as well.

I want to only predict C using value in A with glm():

```
fit.ex = glm(formula = C ~ names(sorted)[2],
         data = data.ex,
         family = binomial(link = "logit"))
```

but then, i'll keep getting the following error message:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = C ~ names(sorted)[2], data = data.ex,: 
variable lengths differ (found for 'names(sorted)[2]')
```

i read this article here and found the as.name() function, but still not working:
http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/pages/looping_strings.htm

and i cannot find anything else thats similar to my problem. 
please, if there is another thread addressing this problem, guide me to it!
or any kind of help is greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Is this what you want - `glm(as.formula(paste("C ~", names(sorted)[2])), data=data.ex)` ?

Comment: Strangely enough, I emailed the UCLA folk a while ago pointing out that the code on their site is overly complex, when `models <- lapply(varlist, function(x) {lm(as.formula(paste("read ~",x)), data = hsb2)})` would suffice.

Comment: or even `forms <- lapply(varlist,reformulate,response="read"); lapply(lm,forms,data=hsb2)` ?

Comment: @BenBolker - neat, but isn't it `lapply(forms,lm,data=hsb2)` ?

Comment: @thelatemail hi i tried your suggested code (1st one) but would get the following error: Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : y values must be 0 <= y <= 1

Comment: @thelatemail actually! nvm. it works with my real data! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Providing an answer based on the comments:

```
sorted = c(A=1,B=2,C=3)
names(sorted) = c("A","B","C")
data.ex = data.frame(A=1:4,B=2:5,C=c(1,0,0,1))
```

Construct a list of formulas:

```
forms <- lapply(names(sorted)[1:2],reformulate,response="C")
models <- lapply(forms,glm,data = data.ex,
                 family = binomial(link = "logit"))
```

Then you can do things like

```
t(sapply(models,coef))
```

The `plyr` package is also handy for this sort of thing (e.g. `plyr::ldply(models,coef)`)